# Check if edit text is empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have tried other questions and answer but have not found a solution.

I am creating a social app that let's people search for others. When I click the search bar I want and type in a letter, for e.g. B, I see the list of users with the name B as expected. But when I removed the B and the search bar is empty, the list of users still shows up.

When nothing is in the search bar, I want the list of users to disappear. This is how I create the edit text in my activity_search:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
android:hint="Search Username Here"
android:textSize="22dp"
android:id="@+id/input"
android:inputType="text"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/round_edit_text" />
```

This is where I set that edit text in the java activity:

```
input = findViewById(R.id.input);
```

And this is the whole java file:

```
EditText input;
RecyclerView FindFriendsRecyclerList;
DatabaseReference mRef;
Query query;

Context mContext;
TextWatcher textWacher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    input = findViewById(R.id.input);
    input.addTextChangedListener(textWacher);

    TextWatcher textWacher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String strText = s.toString();
            if (strText .length() == 0) {
                // removeList();
                FindFriendsRecyclerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Remove list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // showList();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

    FindFriendsRecyclerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    FindFriendsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    findViewById(R.id.search).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            query = mRef.orderByChild("fullname").orderByChild("username").startAt(input.getText().toString()).endAt(input.getText().toString()+"\uf8ff");

            setdata();
        }
    });

    checkIfEmpty();

    if (input.getText().toString().length() == 0) {

        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private void setdata() {

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                    .setQuery(query, User.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, FindFriendsViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull User model) {

                    holder.userName.setText(model.getUsername());
                    holder.userFullName.setText(model.getFullname());
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImageurl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_pic).into(holder.profileImage);

                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            //String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.search_users, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public FindFriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item, viewGroup, false);
                    FindFriendsViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendsViewHolder(view);
                    return viewHolder;
                }
            };

    FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

public static class FindFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView userName, userFullName;
    public CircleImageView profileImage;

    public FindFriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        userFullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
    }
}

public void checkIfEmpty() {

    TextWatcher textWacher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String strText = s.toString();
            if (strText.length() == 0) {
                FindFriendsRecyclerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                // showList();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            FindFriendsRecyclerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see above I have tried the following two ways to check if it's empty:

```
if (input.getText().toString().length() == 0) {

        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

public void checkIfEmpty(View v){

    if(input.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        input.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use TextWatcher for get text state in EditText.

for example,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        input.addTextChangedListener(textWacher);

    }

    TextWatcher textWacher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String strText = s.toString();
            if (strText .length() == 0) {
                // removeList();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "remove", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // showList();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Can you post your log? or just not working without log?

Comment: I see this `2020-10-29 21:21:28.064 20764-20764/com.example.gone E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2020-10-29 21:21:28.065 20764-20764/com.example.gone E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`

Comment: I just updated this method `public void checkIfEmpty()` in my question with what I have now. brb

Comment: I think you miss this.  input.addTextChangedListener(textWacher);
and TextWatcher put global not local variable

Comment: I edit my answer and this code is working. check this.

Comment: That still doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You only call checkIfEmpty on method onCreate if you want yo check on every change if an EditText is empty you need to add to your "input" EditText an onDataChangeListener and check on every mover if is empty.